# fread not working after fseek

Tags: c, file-io, fread

I have a short segment of code that continually reads in 2-byte samples from a .wav file and writes them to a new file, and should be able to seek backwards to repeatedly write sections of the file.  Here's what it looks like:

```
while (readRemaining > 0) {
    while (sizeToRead > 0 && readRemaining > 0) {
        fread(&leftSample, 2, 1, fp);
        fread(&rightSample, 2, 1, fp);
        fwrite(&leftSample, 2, 1, fpout);
        fwrite(&rightSample, 2, 1, fpout);
        sizeToRead -= 4;
        readRemaining -= 4;
    }
    repeatCount++;
    sizeToRead = _grainSize;
    if (repeatCount < REPEATMAX) {
        fseek(fp, -sizeToRead, SEEK_CUR);
        readRemaining += sizeToRead;
    }
    else {
        repeatCount == 0;
    }
}
```

I know it's slow and not optimal, but that's not what I'm worried about.  For some reason, fread stops working after the first iteration through the outer while loop; namely, after the fseek in the first if block.

If REPEATMAX is 1, the file gets read and the new file gets written no problem.  But if there's any repeating, the file gets stuck at the position that was fseek'd to.  I stepped through with gdb and watched it seek correctly, but every subsequent read didn't change leftSample or rightSample and the file pointer would no longer increment.  While debugging I tried to ferror(fp) after the reads failed, but it returned 0.

So, any ideas? Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I should mention that this is really a re-factoring of something that I previously had working.  I would read in an amount equal to _grainSize, then write that REPEATMAX times, then continue.  This is eventually going to be in an embedded system, so I'm trying different methods to test the tradeoff between memory and performance...When I switched to this sample-by-sample method, it stopped working.

Comment: What is grainSize is it total file size or what? Also why are you decreasing           `readRemaining` by 4.

Comment: @Learner grainSize is the size (in bytes) of the "section" that's being read, and/or repeated.  readRemaining decreases by 4 because I read 2 2-byte samples.

Comment: The fread, reads a file from the first line to the end of the file. If you are calling fread multiple times via while loop, then you might have to make sure you fopen and fclose the fread for every while loop. This will ensure that it start on the first line again after reading the first file to the end.

Comment: @user3121023 yes, a simple fopen(/*path*/, 'r')

Comment: @Juniar I don't think that's the issue, I'm reading the file piece by piece and manually keeping track of where I need to be in the file.

Comment: That is right, however how do you begin reading the second file again? The fread might be stuck at the end of the first file after successfully reading it, and so you might have to close then open it again.

Comment: @user3121023 oops, that's right; I wasn't opening as binary technically.  However, after changing that it still isn't working.

Comment: @Juniar fp is the file to be read, fpout is the file that I am writing to.  I debugged with gdb, and saw that the fp pointer successfully fseek'd back to the position it was at at the start of the loop.  feof(fp) returned 0, as did ferror(fp) after the fread didn't work.

Comment: @trillyourself: you are not doing any error handling in this code at all.  Check the return values of `fread()` and `fseek()`, make sure they are not actually failing. Also, since you are always reading 2 samples, you should be checking `sizeToRead` and `readRemaining` for `>= 4` instead of `> 0`.

Comment: Your variables sizeToRead and readRemaining might be -4 at the end then the while loop checks if -4 > 0. You might need to reset these variables before the next while loop begins.

Comment: @user3121023 that worked...well, `fseek(fp, fpos, SEEK_SET)`.  I did an absolute (SEEK_SET) seek in my original algorithm, but I would have expected the relative seek to work as well.  I'm going to leave the question open as I'd like to know why the backwards seek ruins the file reading.  Thank you for the suggestion, not sure why I didn't do it in the first place!

Comment: @RemyLebeau I know the code is light, it was a quick attempt but bare-bones enough that I was (still am) confused why it didn't work.  after the negative `fseek()` (in my test case, this is seeking to 44 bytes from the start of the file), `fread()` returns zero and `ftell(fp)` returns the same location (44) as after the seek.  The rest of the output file gets written with the two samples read before the seek, as `leftSample` and `rightSample` stop changing.

Comment: It also appears you want `repeatCount = 0;` instead of `repeatCount == 0;` and **NOte:** `ftell` advances the file position counter, so if you `ftell` at the end of file, you will set the error condition `EOF` and need to `fseek` (or clear) to reset it.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I just caught that mistake a few minutes ago, shaky hands!  re: ftell, I had no idea.  I can't find any documentation saying ftell moves the pointer...regardless, this seek happens well before the EOF.

Comment: @user3121023 _grainSize is positive, and it's 44 less than the position at seek time; i.e., I seek to 44 bytes from the start of the file.  And after the seek, ftell returns 44, and continues returning 44 no matter how many times I try to read

Comment: This should have been made into a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) a *long* time ago.

Comment: @user3121023 they're all uint32_t, which I understand could mess things up with large values, but their values are small enough to not overflow.  Changing them to int32_t had no effect